Xbox Wireless Controller stopped working on Arch Linux
I have a Xbox Wireless Controller: model 1914, bought in 2021 via Xbox Design Lab.
It used to work perfectly with Arch Linux. It still does, but now only when connected via USB. It stopped connecting via Bluetooth sometimes last year, and I haven't been able to use it in wireless mode since then.
> uname -r
6.8.4-arch1-1

> lsmod | grep xpad
hid_xpadneo            36864  0
xpad                   49152  0
ff_memless             20480  2 xpad,hid_xpadneo

> paru -Qs xpad                                                                                                          
local/xpadneo-dkms 0.9.6-1
    Advanced Linux Driver for Xbox One Wireless Gamepad

> paru -Qs bluez                                                                                                         
local/bluez 5.73-4
    Daemons for the bluetooth protocol stack
local/bluez-libs 5.73-4
    Deprecated libraries for the bluetooth protocol stack
local/bluez-utils 5.73-4
    Development and debugging utilities for the bluetooth protocol stack

It is possible to discover, pair, and trust the controller via bluetoothctl. It is even possible to get a successful connection for a short period of time after pairing, before its status changes to not connected. The light indicator blinks the whole time, even when bluetoothctl briefly reports the controller as being connected.
I have tried to remove and repair the controller many, many times. I also tried to unload and reinstall bluez, bluez-utils, and xpadneo-dkms on numerous occasions.
Many people advise to pair and update the controller via Windows, but I do not have any Windows device or install. I also doubt it would help, as the controller used to work perfectly well via Bluetooth on Arch Linux until it stopped for some unknown reason.
If someone had a solution to offer, I would sincerely appreciate it. While the controller works just fine via USB, I'd rather be able to use it wirelessly once again.
